# Where can I download the latest stable build of Chromium 32bits for Windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, 32-bit, chromium

I've been trying to find the latest stable build of Chromium 32 bits for Windows without any success.

I found the 64 bits version here (51.0.2704.106 at the time of writing) : http://chromium.woolyss.com/

But the only 32 bits version I can find on the web is the latest Dev version (54.0.2788.0).

The posts I found on superuser are a few years old and only point to abandonned projects.

EDIT : No luck. There is no 32 bits build of Chromium including the backports of the Google-Chrome-Stable patches. There is only a 64 bits version (tagged as Stable) on chromium.woolyss.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, Chromium does not have a stable release. The official developers do not release it to end users. So it is continually in development. Google Chrome is the stable release, but is not open-source.

**[Installer (32-bit)](https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/403733/mini_installer.exe)** from the Google repository

mini_installer.exe - 54.0.2788.0
 Released: Monday, July 4, 2016
 Developers: The Chromium Authors

Follow the same instructions as [windows-64-bit-installer](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#windows-64-bit-installer). The same link is also updated when updated versions of Chromium for 32-bit Windows become available.

Comment: But this is the developper version : 54.0.2788.0. The stable one should be 51.0.2704.106.

Comment: Officially, there is no stable release but it's still possible to find the Chromium equivalent of Chrome stable release (51.0.2704.106). A 64 bits build exists on Windows (and is tagged as Stable on http://chromium.woolyss.com/) and is also widely used on Linux distros. I just wanted to know if it was possible to find a 32 bits version too. The dev build doesn't include any bug fix.